# How to nudge employer for offer letter

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, recruitment, hiring-process

So things went like below:

I was contacted by a recruiter for developer role. He asked me my details and if I am interested in the position. I replied to them with affirmation.

Few days passed and I received a test link from the company. I appeared in the test and was able to solve it with 90 score out of 100.

Next day I got a call from them for a Face to face Technical interview. The interviewer was a techie and I did well.

Next day I received a mail from the same recruiter and he asked me if I am available tomorrow for a managerial round? I replied with affirmation.

There were two managers one from APAC area and another from Operational. They took my Interview and I believe that I did well.

Next day I received a mail from APAC hiring manager and he told me that he has received a very good feedback from all my interviewers and he asked me my salary slip of previous three months.
I provided them with it. Then he asked me my expected CTC. I replied to him that I have no idea what should I ask, any thing that they offer me I will accept as the role I am provided matches my stack and I am very much interested.

He then told me that he will discuss this with managers and will come back to me with a proposed offer soon.

---

Next day I asked him for the status and he said me that he will revert me back with a proposed offer soon and told me to have a good weekend.

Now it has been 3 days since I have not heard from him...what should I do?? I mailed to the first guy who sent me the interview request and he seems not replying to me.

Did I lose the opportunity?? Shall I email the APAC recruiter who told me that he will revert back to me with a proposed offer soon?? If yes then what shall I ask him??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: If it's been three days, and there was a weekend on those three days, then pretty much no real time has passed.

Answer (score 4):

> *Did I lose the opportunity??*

Too early to conclude.

> *Shall I email the APAC recruiter who told me that he will revert back to me with a proposed offer soon??*

Yes, you can email a reminder.

> *If yes then what shall I ask him??*

Keep it simple, mention that you are looking for any possible update.

That said, regarding the statement you made

> *I replied to him that I have no idea what should I ask, any thing that they offer me I will accept as the role I am provided matches my stack and I am very much interested.*

You were right not to mention any number, but also do not mention anything they offer will be acceptable. Rephrase your statements, mention that they can come up with an initial offer and you can discuss on that to come to an agreement, but do not commit that you'll accept any offer that they make.

Comment: That last depends on your goals, really.  If he really is desperate and/or motivated, and legitimately does not care much about the money, it's a fine answer.  Not everyone is trying to optimize on the salary debate.

Comment: I will wait for this week and then will email them.